# Convert Nim Regex to string

Tags: nim-lang

I have a compiled [`re.Regex`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/re.html#Regex),
which I use as a regex,
but I also want to show it to the user,
for which I need it as a `string`.
`strformat` seems not to know how to do that.

`re2str.nim`:

```
import re
import strformat

let R_LICENSE = re"(?i)^.*(LICENSE|COPYING).*$"

echo fmt"We are using the regex '{R_LICENSE}' to look for a license file."
```

compile and run with:

```bash
nim compile --run re2str.nim
```

output:

```bash
re2str.nim(6, 9) template/generic instantiation of `fmt` from here
/home/user/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.6.4/lib/pure/strformat.nim(568, 23) Error: type mismatch: got <Regex>
but expected one of:
func `$`(x: float | float32): string
...
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution is, to circumvent the issue
by keeping the string the regex was compiled from
available separately.

`str2re.nim`:

```
import re
import strformat

let RS_LICENSE = "(?i)^.*(LICENSE|COPYING).*$"
let R_LICENSE = re(RS_LICENSE)

echo fmt"We are using the regex '{RS_LICENSE}' to look for a license file."
```

compile and run with:

```bash
nim compile --run str2re.nim
```

output:

```bash
...
We are using the regex '(?i)^.*(LICENSE|COPYING).*$' to look for a license file.
```